# not kill a process

Tags: process

I want to write a program that can not close it
In other words, they can not kill process .

The solution of the process of closure for less than the other way is to do a good job
I have another solution?

Comment: Any particular operating system?

Comment: for windows operating system .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Linux, this is not quite possible from userspace because there are signals like 
SIGKILL that cannot be ignored or handled.

If you have access to kernel, than you could write a kernel moudule which puts the current process in state TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE and thus no one could kill it.

Answer (score 0):

please specify your question in detail.

i think you have facing error on previous activity is onResume();

you have to on resume method for removing this error.

in onResume() method you can call finish(); method for stop activity.

Comment: I'm not sure how you confused "windows" with "android".